# Django ORM , Doubts regarding normalization

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, database-normalization

I have a table in which data gets written in a very fast rate (around 40000 writes per minute)

```
class dummyclass():
      field1 = models.CharField()
      field2 = models.IntegerField()
      ...
      field6 = models.DecimalField()
```

There are about 6 to 8 fields in it which is constantly changing

So i decided to split this class into six different classes like this

```
class dummyclass():
     field1 = models.CharField()
     field2 = modles.CharField()

class subdummyclass():
     dummy = models.ForiegnKeyField(dummyclass)
     field3 = models.CharField()

class subdummyclass1():
     dummy = models.ForiegnKeyField(dummyclass)
     field4 = models.CharField()

class subdummyclass2():
     dummy = models.ForiegnKeyField(dummyclass)
     field5 = models.CharField()

class subdummyclass3():
     dummy = models.ForiegnKeyField(dummyclass)
     field6 = models.CharField()
```

is there any advantage in splitting data to different tables like this or am i overdoing this (overnormalization) .

Any help is appreciated
Thanks and regards

Comment: Normalization replaces a table by others based on the FDs & JDs that that restrict what values the table can have. You haven't given any relevant info. An answer would be textbook chapters on normalization, read some. But anyway there are benefits to recording transactions as-is (formally, logging). But again your question is too general.